# How to combine 2 tabel with total value in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, sum, relation

Please help me, to show total score percriteria in query laravel. this's my table criteria

[image]

This's my table relation

[image]

I want the result is

My expect result is like this

[image]

Comment: Please show us your model and the relationship.

Comment: I've find solution, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've created models for your tables, try something like :

```
 $result = Criteria::join('relation', 'relation.criteria_id', '=' ,'criteria.id')
    ->select('criteria_name', DB::raw('SUM(score) as TotalScore'))
    ->groupBy('criteria_id')
    ->get();
```